# Pseudo-terminals vs. a pair of pipes

Tags: pipe, system-calls, fifo, ipc, pty

Why are pseudo-terminals a seperate feature on Unix-like systems? What makes them superior to a pair of pipes or FIFOs for implementing terminal emulators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminals are different from other forms of I/O, and a terminal emulator needs to present itself as a terminal.

- A terminal (including a pseudoterminal) has certain attributes, such as its line length and supported control sequences. Programs can ask for these, for example, in general `ls` will determine whether its output is going to a terminal, and then adjust its colors and tabulation to match the terminal.

  You can test this: `ls | cat` will not give you separate columns. A pseudoterminal is used to pass the appropriate values for the terminal emulator.

  As another example, programs like `sudo` and `ssh` will, for security reasons, read the password from the terminal directly, you can't pipe them in.
- Terminals are used to control processes. If you press `^C`, the terminal will send `SIGINT` to *its foreground process*. This is the terminal's job. This means that, in order for things like `^C` to work, there must be a terminal.

  Similarly, hanging up on a terminal (or on a modern system, closing the terminal emulator's window) will send `SIGHUP` to all processes associated with it.

  The pseudoterminal handles this, a pair of pipes can't.

  In general, all processes except daemons have a controlling terminal. You can use `ps` to tell you which processes belong to which terminals.

Comment: While your answer is correct (it proves that a pty cannot be replaced with a pair of pipe), another questions rises: can one replace a pty with a pair of pipes *and* a bit of userspace code?

Comment: @cubuspl42 That depends on what you want to do. It might require more than "a bit" of userspace code. Also, for anyone who is curious to learn more about this sort of thing, check out [this article.](http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html) It's pretty good stuff.